# Use a MediaWiki template argument both parsed and unparsed

Tags: mediawiki, template, markup

Suppose I have a simple template `Foo`

```
The wikitext

 {{{1}}}

renders as

<blockquote>{{{2}}}</blockquote>
```

So including `{{Foo|<nowiki>'''bold''' and ''italics''</nowiki>|'''bold''' and ''italics''}}` in a page renders as

> The wikitext
>
> ```
> '''bold''' and ''italics''
> ```
>
> renders as
>
> > **bold** and *italics*

Is there any way to reduce the duplication required to use template `Foo`? That is, either modify `Foo` or call it via another template in such a way that the user only needs to specify the desired wikitext *once*, instead of two times?

I don't really care if it would be as

```
{{DRYFoo|<nowiki>'''bold''' and ''italics''</nowiki>}}
```

or

```
{{FooDRY|'''bold''' and ''italics''}}
```

and I'd be satisfied by something that used [`subst:`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Substitution) to expand something else into a normal call to `Foo`.

The [rules for order of evaluation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates#Order_of_evaluation) would seem to rule out `FooDRY`, and I've been unable to find a template/parser function that would re-expand wikitext to make `DRYFoo` work.

Comment: My current solution is to put the template argument in a separate page, and then use `msgnw:`, e.g. `{{Foo|msgnw:FooArg|{{FooArg}}}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
The wikitext

 {{{1}}}

renders as

<blockquote>{{#tag:nowiki|{{{2}}}}}</blockquote>
```

should do the job (`{{#tag}}` turns XML-style tags into normal parserfuncions, ie. flips the evaluation order).